# I thought ruby was synchronous language.. but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my rails app and trying to add authority by adding a method made with gem called cancancan. so there are two methods below.

```
 def find_review
   @review = Review.find(params[:id])
 end

 def authorize_user!
   unless can? :manage, @review
     redirect_to product_path(@review.product)
   end
 end
```

and there are two cases. case 1: calling the methods inside destroy action

```
def destroy
  find_review
  authorize!
  @product = @review.product
  @reviews = @product.reviews
  @review.destroy
end
```

and case 2: calling the methods using before_action method

```
before_action :find_review, :authorize!, only: [:destroy]

def destroy
  @product = @review.product
  @reviews = @product.reviews
  @review.destroy
  redirect_to product_path(@product), notice: 'Review is deleted'
end
```

I get that using before_action(case 2) redirects unauthorized user even before calling the action so it makes sense. What I am wondering is in case 1, why authorize method doesn't interrupt and redirect the user before destroying the review ? It actually redirects, but after deleting the review. but I thought ruby is synchronous..

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, your `authorize!` does not interrupt the request, only adds a header and then carries on with the destruction and whatnot. A good reliable way to interrupt the flow from within a nested method call is to raise an exception. Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController
  NotAuthorizedError = Class.new(StandardError)

  rescue_from NotAuthorizedError do
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def authorize!
    unless can?(:manage, @review)
      fail NotAuthorizedError
    end
  end

  def destroy
    find_review
    authorize! # if user is not authorized, the code below won't run
               # because of the exception
    @product = @review.product
    @reviews = @product.reviews
    @review.destroy
  end
end
```

#### Update

There must be something off with your integration of cancan, [because it **does** include an exception-raising `authorize!`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions). You should be able to do this:

```
  def destroy
    find_review
    authorize! :manage, @review # can raise CanCan::AccessDenied
    @product = @review.product
    @reviews = @product.reviews
    @review.destroy
  end
```

Or, better

```
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def destroy
    @product = @review.product
    @reviews = @product.reviews
    @review.destroy
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

In case 1 you need to `return` from method when doing redirect to halt execution, and use [ActionController::Metal#performed?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-performed-3F) to test whether redirect already happended:

```
def authorize_user!
  unless can? :manage, @review
    redirect_to product_path(@review.product) and return 
  end
end

def destroy
  find_review
  authorize!; return if performed?
  @product = @review.product
  @reviews = @product.reviews
  @review.destroy
end
```

There's no "asynchronous behaviour". `redirect_to` actually only adds appropriate headers for the response object, it's not halt execution of your delete request.

Comment: Adding that `return` won't change anything. The other part of the answer is correct.

Comment: Yep, this should work, despite looking a little un-ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, you need to return from method when doing redirect to halt execution

```
return redirect_to product_path(@review.product)
```

In case 2, you have to make some change in you authorize method.

scenario 1. For a specific user role can't manage Review model at all

```
unless can?(:manage, Review)
 redirect_to product_path(@review.product)
end
```

replace the instance variable with model name

scenario 2, some users in the specific role can manage the review, but others in some role can't mange review.

In this case, you need to load the review object before calling can function

```
def authorize_user!
  find_review
  unless can?( :manage, @review)
    redirect_to product_path(@review.product)
  end
end
```

I think my answer will help you.

Comment: appreciate your reply. but first of all, what I am curious about is the asynchronous behaviour. I noticed that delete request occurs first and then get request has occured..

Comment: case 1 is already implicit return. Adding explicit return won't change anything.